# Circle intersect MySQL

Tags: mysql, geospatial

I have two circle on a map with Longitude, Latitude (point()) and Radius and now I would know if there is a SQL function that return true if those circle intersect ?

Thx for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
If(ST_Distance(POINT(Long1, Lat1),POINT(Long2, Lat2))<=Radius1+Radius2, "INTERSECT","NO INTERSECTION")
```

Which is basically asking if the distance between the centers of the circles is <= the sum of their radii. If it is - they intersect.

Answer (score 0):

Try ST_***() functions available in MySQL 5.6.

More information.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html

https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/21/using-the-new-mysql-spatial-functions-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/

Comment: Yes but all ST_***() functions use point and not circle with radius.

Answer (score 0):

You indeed need to use the ST_*() functions **and** spatial operator functions, but Zamrony's answer is rather vague. So, what you need to do is to convert your circles into geometry data types and then you can use st_intersect() to see if the 2 circles intersect:

1. Use [ST_Buffer()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-buffer) function to convert point and radius into geometry data type:

> Returns a geometry that represents all points whose distance from the
>   geometry value g is less than or equal to a distance of d, or NULL if
>   any argument is NULL.

Pls read the description of [ST_Buffer_Strategy()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-buffer-strategy) as well on how points making up the circle geometries are determined.

2. Use [ST_Intersects()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-relation-functions-object-shapes.html#function_st-intersects) function to determine if the two geometries intersect each other.

Comment: Ok I will try this too.